# datetime to timestamp javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

i have this time format :

```
DateTime(2015, 5, 11, 12, 0, 0)
```

i would like to know if i can convert it into a time stamp.

i have made this convert function from ISO 8601 to Timestamp and i would like to know if i can adapt it to this time format :

```js
var myDate = new Date("2017-07-31T15:30:00+0000");
var offset = myDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

var withOffset = myDate.getTime();
var withoutOffset = withOffset - offset;

console.log(myDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60 * 1000)
console.log('with Offset  ' + withOffset);
console.log('without Offset (timeStamp of your timezone) ' +withoutOffset);
```

Comment: see this link https://coderwall.com/p/rbfl6g/how-to-get-the-correct-unix-timestamp-from-any-date-in-javascript

Comment: Also have a look at moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

did you try

> `Date.parse(your date here)/1000`
>
> `Date.parse(new Date(2015, 5, 11, 12, 0, 0))/1000`

Comment: Cool to see 'advanced' native `Date` functionality!

Comment: sounds like a cool feature but...

Date.parse(2015, 5, 11, 12, 0, 0)/1000
(Date is may 11th 2015 at 12:00:00) and i have this timestamp :
1420070400
which is refer to january 1st 2015 at 01am ...
sound like a problem... there is a way to fix it ?

Comment: use this Date.parse(new Date(2015, 5, 11, 12, 0, 0))/1000

Answer (score 1):

you can use the library momentjs to convert it.

Here you are assigning an instance of momentjs to CurrentDate:

```
var CurrentDate = moment();
```

Here just a string, the result from default formatting of a momentjs instance:

```
var CurrentDate = moment().format();
```

And here the number of seconds since january of... well, unix timestamp:

```
var CurrentDate = moment().unix();
```

[momentjs guide](https://momentjs.com/guides/)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing dates is a pain in JavaScript as there's no extensive native support. However you could do something like the following by relying on the `Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])` constructor signature of the Date object.

```
var dateString = '17-09-2013 10:08',
dateTimeParts = dateString.split(' '),
timeParts = dateTimeParts[1].split(':'),
dateParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('-'),
date;

date = new Date(dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1, dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);

console.log(date.getTime()); //1379426880000
console.log(date); //Tue Sep 17 2013 10:08:00 GMT-0400
```