# how to convert days hours min sec into timestamp

Tags: javascript, time

I need to convert days hours min sec into a timestamp

eg:timerTime: "0-47-15-31";

into timestamp 1620148830209

can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [datetime to timestamp javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345450/datetime-to-timestamp-javascript)

Comment: A timestamp indicates the number of seconds elapsed since 01/01/1970 00:00:00 UTC. You need full date to convert into a timestamp. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Convert DD:HH:MM:SS to milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419289/javascript-convert-ddhhmmss-to-milliseconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are working in UTC.

```js
function getTimeStamp(dateString) {
   splitted = dateString.split('-')
   var date = new Date();
   date.setDate(splitted[0])
   splitted.shift();
   date.setHours.apply(date,splitted);
   return date.getTime();
}

getTimeStamp("0-47-15-31");
/// return 1619891131992
```

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp from when?

Here are all the tools you need.

```js
const timerTime = "0-47-15-31";
const [days,hours,minutes,seconds] = timerTime.split("-")
const d = new Date()
d.setDate(d.getDate() + +days); // cast the days to number
d.setHours(hours,minutes,seconds,0)
console.log(d,d.getTime(),1620148830209); // difference is timezone offset


// timestamp 1620148830209
```